# Ajax to Python Pyramid data

Tags: python, ajax, pyramid

So far, I have managed to take a bunch of HTML elements for whose contentEditable attribute is True and join their id's and HTML data together to make an Ajax data string. I can get the serialized data back to the server, no problem.  For example,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#save").click(function(){
        var ajax_string = ''
        $( "[contenteditable=True]" ).each(function( intIndex ){
            ajax_string = ajax_string + '&' + $("[contenteditable=True]")[intIndex].id + ':' + $(this).html();
        });
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"/episode_edit/{{ episode.ID_Episode }}",
            data:ajax_string,
            success:function(result){
                <!--alert( ajax_string );-->
                }
        });
    });
});
```

On the server:

```
for r in request.params: print r
```

I get strings:

```
AltTitle:some Alt Title
PrintTitle:The Print Title
Notes:A bunch o' notes.
```

My dilema now is that I need to convert each `request.param` string into a dictionary object, so I can map it back to my database model. I can think of some very ugly ways of doing this, but what is the best way?

Comment: It's because you're doing it wrong. You should send your data as normal application/x-www-form-urlencoded. That is url?key1=value1&key2=value2. Not url?key1:value1&key2:value2.

Comment: Thanks Antoine, but unfortunately, when I change the ':' to '=' in my javascript, the results still get returned to the server as strings and everything from and including the '=' is stripped.  eg. Instead of `"AltTitle:some Alt Title"` I get `"AltTitle"`.

Comment: Again, you should look at the developer tools in your browser. Send the data as url?key1=value1&key2=value2 and look at the value posted. Then, once you realize the value posted are right, go to your Python code and use `for key, value in request.params.items(): print key, value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you want to convert **each** request.param string into a dictionary object, but is that what you meant? It looks like each string is just a key/value pair.

You can pretty simply create a dictionary from those values using:

```
opts = {}
for r in request.params:
    parts = r.split(':', 1)
    if len(parts) == 2:
        opts[parts[0]] = parts[1]
    else:
        # some error condition
```

Comment: I think its a shame that we have to do that, but that is a great way of getting it done.  Thanks tubs @Michael Merickel.

Comment: Well given how you're constructing the request in javascript, you'll have to parse it in that fashion I think. You could always serialize the dictionary in javascript into a json format that you could just json.loads(...) in python.

Comment: Ok, I'll look into that.  Your afore mentioned method is working fine but getting it out of javascript properly would best.  Thank you again, Matt.